# Logistic regression error

Tags: r, statistics, glm

```
Test <- read.table("C:/Users/ARAB/Documents/user_table.csv", header=T)
testlog <- glm(Conv ~ active_days, family=binomial("logit"))
```

this is a code i am trying to run in R but am getting error

```
"Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Conv' not found"
```

This is my first day in R. Please help me. 
Also I can see `Conv` in data when i am using `view()` command. `Conv` is the outcome variable containing 1/0. Also in sas or spss we have the option of modelling 1 or 0 in a binary logit model. How can we use that in R or does this error have something to do with that.

Comment: In reply to your last sentence: perhaps `glm(1-Conv ~ active_days, ...)` will do?  (i.e. just convert 'successes' to 'failures' on the fly by subtracting the response variable from 1)?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by @blindJesse you need to specify the data.frame where the variables are contained by using `data=data.frame` inside `glm` function or using one of the below alternatives

```
utils::data(anorexia, package="MASS") # using some R data

# Option 1 (the best one)
glm(Postwt ~ Prewt + Treat + offset(Prewt), family = gaussian, data = anorexia)

# Option 2: Using 'with'
with(anorexia, glm(Postwt ~ Prewt + Treat + offset(Prewt), family = gaussian))

# Option 3: Using 'attach' I don't like it
attach(anorexia)
glm(Postwt ~ Prewt + Treat + offset(Prewt), family = gaussian)

detach(anorexia) # detaching the data.

# Option 4: Using '$'
glm(anorexia$Postwt ~ anorexia$Prewt + Treat + offset(Prewt), family = gaussian)
```

A fifth option could be using `[` which could be very similar to that in fourth option.

Comment: @Abhishek Ray if one of these answers meet your needs then you should check it as accepted by clicking in the green tickmark.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the data.frame, e.g.

```
testlog <- glm(Conv ~ active_days, data=Test, family=binomial("logit"))
```

Answer (score 0):

another reason for this error is 
if you don't leave space between the + sign , glm throws this error

- Sasken